# db_query question

Tags: 7, database

I'm writing a custom module and trying to use the db_query functions instead of just doing straight MySQL calls.

Here's my query.

```
$nid = $node->nid;
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {field_data_field_room_rates} WHERE field_room_rates_target_id = :nid', array(':nid' => $nid));
drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($result, TRUE) .'</pre>');
```

...and here's what I get back.

```
DatabaseStatementBase Object
(
    [dbh] => DatabaseConnection_mysql Object
        (
            [needsCleanup:protected] => 
            [target:protected] => default
            [key:protected] => default
            [logger:protected] => 
            [transactionLayers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [drupal_transaction] => drupal_transaction
                )

            [driverClasses:protected] => Array
                (
                    [SelectQuery] => SelectQuery
                    [DatabaseTransaction] => DatabaseTransaction
                    [InsertQuery] => InsertQuery_mysql
                    [UpdateQuery] => UpdateQuery
                )

            [statementClass:protected] => DatabaseStatementBase
            [transactionSupport:protected] => 1
            [transactionalDDLSupport:protected] => 
            [temporaryNameIndex:protected] => 0
            [connectionOptions:protected] => Array
                (
                    [database] => my_db
                    [username] => user
                    [password] => pw
                    [host] => localhost
                    [port] => 
                    [driver] => mysql
                    [prefix] => Array
                        (
                            [default] => 
                        )

                )

            [schema:protected] => 
            [prefixes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [default] => 
                )

            [prefixSearch:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {
                    [1] => }
                )

            [prefixReplace:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

        )

    [queryString] => SELECT * FROM field_data_field_room_rates WHERE field_room_rates_target_id = :nid
)
```

if I were querying the SQL manually the query would be:

SELECT * FROM field_data_field_room_rates WHERE field_room_rates_target_id =2164

and it would yield back the proper row of items...which this doesn't seem to be giving.  All it seems to be giving back is Drupal database info.

What am I doing wrong?  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fecth the results from the `$result` object. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174 for reference.

For instance, you might do something like:

```
$row = $result->fetch();
```

Hope it helps,